# Robolectric Run Handler post

Tags: android, handler, robolectric

I am having trouble testing `Handler` code with Robolectric. For example:

```
public class Client {
  private Handler mMainThreadHandler;

  public interface Callback{
    void ok();
  }

  public Client() {
    mMainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  }

  public void doSomeStuff(Callback callback){
    //doing...
    mMainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable(){
      @Override public void run() {
        callback.ok();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How do I run the code in the `Runnable` immediately? It doesn't run before my test is done executing.

Comment: Did you call Client.doSomeStuff() on main thread or background thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should make a job:

```
Robolectric.runUiThreadTasks();
```

or if there several tasks scheduled:

```
Robolectric.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
```

Answer (score 11):

For Robolectric version 3.0 you should use:
`org.robolectric.Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler`
or 
`org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasks`
`org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks`

Reference: [2.4 to 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide)

Answer (score 4):

In Robolectrie 3.0 you can do

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("test");
thread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {run(){
  int a = 0;
}};
((ShadowLooper) ShadowExtractor.extract(thread.getLooper())).idle(); // this will execute line int a = 0;
```